# No content returns from Scrapy and Instagram

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to get the tags text from an instagram image, for example: https://www.instagram.com/p/CHPoTitFdEz/, but Scrapy returns no content.

In the Scrapy shell I have written:

`response.xpath('//span[@class=""]/a[@class="xil3i"]/text()').get()`

or

`response.xpath('//span[@class=""]/a[@class="xil3i"]/text()').extract()`

Which should get me to the content of first tag. However, Scrapy shell returns no content or an empty array. I use Scrapy for other, simpler websites and everything always went fine. I also tried to include more divs but the content is always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First rule of thumb of using scrapy is to open view page source on browser. We mostly get the same response in scrapy. If we are getting blocked then that is a totally different question.

Upon viewing source we can see that this website is dynamically loading all the content using ajax requests as nothing is present in the page source. Now you can try searching for your desired content in network tab and then you can try replicating the request that contains that. Or else you can use splash. Documentation for splash can be found [here](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html).

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I wait to see if the command proposed by Sharmiko may work, otherwise I am glad to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to look at the response body, you will see that instagram page is not fully loaded. `POST` data is saved in other tags. For example:

```
<meta property="instapp:hashtags" content="cyberpunk" />
```

So, you may want to change selector path and extract information from meta tags.
In this case it would be:

```
response.xpath('//meta[@property="instapp:hashtags"]')
```

and you will get your content back. In case you need other information first try inspecting `response.body` and see if it is there.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I tried to run your command but it still returns an empty list: did it work for you?

Comment: yes, it works for me. Also, check if you are being blocked by `robots.txt`. If that's the case you can put `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False` in your `settings.py` file.

Comment: Also, did you try to inspect `response.body`? After making sure you are not blocked by `robots.txt` check if the response body contains those `meta` tags with desired content.

Comment: I changed ```ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False``` but when I run the spider I still do not see the tags. My spider is: 

import scrapy


class TagsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tags"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.instagram.com/p/CHPoTitFdEz/'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = f'quotes-{page}.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)

Comment: It output a HTML file where the tags are not there. Any other idea?

Comment: can you paste html file somewhere and share it with me so I can also see the content?

Comment: Thank you for you help; I saw that if I disabled js when inspecting the instagram page, the page does not show anything, so I necessarily need to use splash or similar. The problem was that everything was coming from js.